# Retrieving the Sender’s email address from Outlook 365

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office365, digital-signature

Following bit of code stopped working after upgrading from Office 2010 on W7, to Office 365 on W10.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim OL As Outlook.Application
    Dim ST As Outlook.Store
    Dim DSI As Outlook.Folder
    Dim Email As Outlook.MailItem

    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    'Find Primary Mailbox
    For Each ST In OL.GetNamespace("MAPI").Stores
        If ST.ExchangeStoreType = olPrimaryExchangeMailbox Then
            Set DSI = ST.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
            Exit For
        End If
        Set ST = Nothing
    Next

    Const PR_SMTP_ADDRESS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E"

    For Each Email In DSI.Items
        Debug.Print Email.Sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
    Next

    Set Email = Nothing
    Set DSI = Nothing
    Set ST = Nothing
    Set OL = Nothing

End Sub
```

It now returns a 287 runtime error “Application-defined or object-defined error” on this line.

```
Debug.Print Email.Sender.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_SMTP_ADDRESS)
```

My research suggests this is a trust issue; so I tried adding a signature to the code, but that didn’t work.

The only way I got it to work was when run directly on Outlook VBA with a signature applied to the code.  But I need to be able to run this from excel VBA.

Any suggestions?

The purpose of the code is to identify emails in the default Send Items folder which have been sent with a shared mailbox, and move them to a separate folder (code has been cut-down above to just show the error at hand).  As I said, the code was working fine prior to the upgrade.

Comment: `PropertyAccessor` is a property of a `MailItem`.  It is not a property of `MailItem.Sender`.  Delete `.Sender`.

Comment: My experiments have found no difference between `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E")` and `MailItem.SenderEmailAddress`.

Comment: You are wrong - the Sender property returns an instance of the AddressEntry which has the `PropertyAccessor` property. So, the code is correct!

Comment: @TonyDallimore there is a difference whenever a mailitem has been send from a different mailbox (e.g. 'sent on behalf of' mail items)

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev.  You are correct, `Sender` does have property `PropertyAccessor`.  I would never have thought to look so thanks for that information.  However, I cannot get the schema address in the question to work on my system with either `MailItem` or `MailItem.Sender`.  Do you know where I can find a list of the schemas for `MailItem.Sender`?

Comment: @Skytunnel.  I had not read your question carefully enough.  You are using schema "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E" which I cannot get to work with either `MailItem` or `MailItem.Sender`.  My comment would have been correct if I have said "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0C1F001E".  I will have to try the schema suggested by Dmitry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to avoid the security prompt by searching (`Items.Restrict` or `Items.Find/FindNext`) the Sent Items folder on the `PidTagSenderSmtpAddress` MAPI property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x5D01001F`).

Also, there is no reason to loop through the stores - `Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder()` will give you the folder from the default store anyway.

Comment: Great answer.  But unable to make it work with the "@" character in the filter?  Had to do `ci_startswith 'name@'´.  Is there any escape char that can be used to include the "@" in the filter?

Comment: Here is what’s worked for me…

MailItem.Items.Restrict("@SQL=””http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0065001E”” = ‘name@domain.com’")

 

Is there an easier way to find these DASL names??  It took me countless amounts of googling to stubble upon this one!?

Comment: Sure, you can see them in OutlookSpy (http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) - click IMessage button, select the property you need, look at the DASL edit box.

Comment: would Microsoft not list them anywhere themselves?? It's too much effort to get new software approved at my place.

Comment: OutlookSpy installer does not require admin privileges to install.

Comment: well I got prompted for an admin password when attempting it.

Comment: Worst case, you can extract the dll with the right bitness from http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/download/OutlookSpy.zip to any local folder and install the dll using regsvr32.exe.

Answer (score 1):

It seems Microsoft enforced security rules for Outlook Automation. There are possible routes where you can go to:

1. Use a low-level code on which Outlook is based on - Extended MAPI or just any other third-party wrappers around this API such as Redemption.
2. Use third-party components designed for turning off such security triggers in Outlook - [Security Manager for Microsoft Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/outlook-security/index.php).
3. Set up a group policy to avoid such triggers.
4. Set up a valid antivirus software on the system.